# Dynamically change radiobuttonlist name in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my aspx file, I have a drop down list

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Dlist" CssClass="dropdown" AutoPostBack="true" SelectedIndexChanged="CtrlChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select item" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I have a radio button list

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" RepeatColumns="1"
    RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem>Option 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Option 2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Now I want to change the name of one or both of the radio buttons in the radio button list after something has been selected from the dropdown list using C#. Below is my attempt but not working.

```
protected void CtrlChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //attempting to change text of first radio button when item has been selected from dropdownlist
    RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text = "Text changed!";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is `OnSelectedIndexChanged`, not `SelectedIndexChanged`. And the ListItems of a RadioButtonList are index based, so you need to access them like this:

```
protected void CtrlChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Text = "NewValue 1";
    RadioButtonList1.Items[1].Text = "NewValue 2";
}
```

Your way does change the text, but only for the item you set the SelectedIndex of. And it will change the selected radiobutton to the first one, should one already have been selected.